# Invertible elements of $\mathbb Z_9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, integers

I have this problem: Prove that $x=[1]_{9}+[3]_{9}[b]_{9}$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_{9}$, for all $[b]_{9}\in \mathbb{Z}_{9}$ and find the inverse.

In empirical way i found that $x\in\{[1]_{9}, [4]_{9}, [7]_{9}\}$,  so $x$ is invertible for all $[b]_{9}\in \mathbb{Z}_{9}$, since the inverses of $\mathbb{Z}_{9}$ are $\{[1]_{9},[2]_{9}, [4]_{9}, [5]_{9},[7]_{9}, [8]_{9},\}$, but is there a rigorous proof to prove that?

Thanks in advance. Best wishes.

Comment: Well, the only candidates for $\gcd(a, 9)$ are $1,3,9$ and it is clear that $1+3b$ is prime to $3$, hence it must be prime to $9$.

Comment: Hint: use the fact that $a$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_9 \iff \gcd(a, 9) = 1$.

Comment: So, since gcd$(1+3b, 3)=1$ then gcd$(1+3b,9)=1 \iff 1+3b$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_{9}$. Is correct? and how i can find the inverse? thanks

Comment: If by "empirical" you mean "exhaustive examination of cases," well, that is a rigorous proof.

Comment: $(1+3b)(1-3b)\equiv1\pmod9$

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes :D! i thought there was a different way; instead as you said, i examineted all the cases

Comment: Well, there are different ways, maybe better ways, but there's nothing unrigorous about your way.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you. Yes i found better ways. I probably expressed myself badly. but, thank you and thanks all of you

Answer (score 1):

More generally, this holds in any ring:

> If $u^n=0$ then $1+u$ is invertible and the inverse is $1-u+u^2-\cdots+(-1)^{n-1} u^{n-1}$.

In your case, $u=3b$ and $u^2=0$ and so the inverse is $1-u=1-3b$.